# CakePHP Formhelper with Bootstrap Accordion

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

In CakePHP, I've created a multiple select field populated with a bunch of checkboxes. I am trying to style it into a bootstrap accordion so every optgroup can collapse.

The input:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Subject', array(
    'class' => 'checkbox-inline no_indent',
    'type' => 'select',
    'multiple' => 'checkbox',
    'options' => $options
));
$options = array(
    __('Primary') => array(
        '1' => __('General'), 
        '2' => __('English'),
        '3' => __('Maths'),
        '4' => __('Science')            
    ),
    __('Secondary') => array(
        '5' => __('General'), 
        '6' => __('English'),
        '7' => __('Maths'),
        '8' => __('Science')            
    )
);
```

The style I want it to change into:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    <legend>Primary</legend>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="checkbox-inline no_indent"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Subject][Subject][]" value="1" id="SubjectSubject1" /><label for="SubjectSubject1">General</label></div>
                <div class="checkbox-inline no_indent"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Subject][Subject][]" value="2" id="SubjectSubject2" /><label for="SubjectSubject2">English</label></div>
                <div class="checkbox-inline no_indent"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Subject][Subject][]" value="3" id="SubjectSubject3" /><label for="SubjectSubject3">Maths</label></div>
                <div class="checkbox-inline no_indent"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Subject][Subject][]" value="4" id="SubjectSubject4" /><label for="SubjectSubject4">Science</label></div>                       
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    <legend>Secondary</legend>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="checkbox-inline no_indent"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Subject][Subject][]" value="5" id="SubjectSubject5" /><label for="SubjectSubject5">General</label></div>
                <div class="checkbox-inline no_indent"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Subject][Subject][]" value="6" id="SubjectSubject6" /><label for="SubjectSubject6">English</label></div>
                <div class="checkbox-inline no_indent"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Subject][Subject][]" value="7" id="SubjectSubject7" /><label for="SubjectSubject7">Maths</label></div>
                <div class="checkbox-inline no_indent"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Subject][Subject][]" value="8" id="SubjectSubject8" /><label for="SubjectSubject8">Science</label></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I did some searching but I could not find a way to modify the markup per opt group.. not sure if there is actually a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always alias the default helpers with your custom helpers. This way when calling `Form:input` you can have your own function to create your accordion.

In other words inside folder `View\Helpers` you can create a class named `BootstrapFormHelper`

Then in this class you write

```
App::uses('FormHelper', 'View/Helper');

class BootstrapFormHelper extends FormHelper {

    /**
     * input method
     *
     * @param string $fieldName
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function input($fieldName, $options = array()) {
        if(isset($options['class'] && issset($options['class']['checkbox-inline']){
            //put your code to create the Accordion
        }
        return parent::input($fieldName, $options);
    }
}
```

Inside you AppController:

```
public $helpers = array(
    'Form' => array(
        'className' => 'BootstrapForm'
    ),
)
```

Now when you call `Form::input` the method that will be executed will be the method of `BootstrapForm::input()`

See the last paragraph here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html#using-and-configuring-helpers. Hope it helps.

**Edit:**

An example could be:

```
public function input($fieldName, $options = array()) {
    if(
        isset($options['type']) && $options['type'] == 'select') &&
        isset($options['multiple']) && $options['multiple'] == 'checkbox') &&            
        isset($options['class'] && 
        issset($options['class']['checkbox-inline'])
      )
        {
        return $this->inputAccordionCheckboxes($fieldname, $options);
    }
    return parent::input($fieldName, $options);
}

private function inputAccordionCheckboxes($fieldname, $options){
    $chkOptions = $options['options'];
    $string = '';

    $string = 'Write the panel opening tags and the legend you need';
    foreach($chkOptions as $field => $options){
        $string .= 'open the tags for accordion';
        $string .= 'create your checkboxes with an parent::input function according to your needs';
        $string .= 'close the tags for accordion';
    }

    $string = 'Write the close tags for the panel';
    return $string;
}
```

Don't know if my logic helps you or it confuses you more.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. Extending FormHelper allows you to set a bunch of bootstrap classes as default so you don't have to set it individually. I can do something like this within the `if` statement:  `$class = array('class' => 'form-control');`  `$options = array_merge($class, $options);` But these are the things Cake already allows me to do. But there is no options in Cake to modify legend tag and add divs to wrap the tag.

Comment: Yes there is. ``$options['before']``, ``$options['between']``, ``$options['separator']``, and ``$options['after']``. Furthermore with these function you can create your custom options and return them. For example in I can add an ``option['icon']`` and return a font-awesome icon with the input when calling the method.

Comment: Still no luck.. Whatever custom option I set, Cake treats it as an attribute in the input tag. I also tried tweaking the `'format' => array('label', 'before', 'input', 'between', 'error', 'after')` but is only arranging the order of `input` and `label`.. etc, not optgroup. Would you mind editing the codes above so I know where I do it wrong?..

Comment: I totally follow you. It works! Thanks so much for your patience Mponos. You saved my life.